# Force Jekyll --watch to regenerate a specific page when another page changes

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I wrote a Jekyll plugin that creates a custom index of certain portions of my site--those pages using the layout `outline`. It's currently implemented as a site hook running pre-render.

When I have Jekyll generate the site, it works as expected. However, when I'm developing, I normally run Jekyll with `--watch`. When I edit an `outline` page, the page gets regenerated as expected. However, the index doesn't get regenerated. I presume this is because the index page doesn't actually change.

How can I make Jekyll regenerate the index when necessary? I would even accept regenerating the index any time any portion of the site is regenerated, whether or not it was necessary.

In case you care, here's the essence of the plugin:

```rb
    Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :pre_render do |site, payload|
      destination = payload[:site][:pages].find {|p| p.permalink == '/ministry/outlines/'}
      # Generate content here...
      destination.content = destination.content.sub(/INSERT_PLUGIN_CONTENT_HERE/, generated_content.to_html(2))
    end
```

Comment: To force Jekyll --watch to regenerate a specific page when another page changes, you can use the Jekyll::Hooks.register method to register a custom hook that runs after the render phase. This hook can then manually trigger the regeneration of the index page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How do you manually trigger the regeneration of a page?